# CodeIgniter can't remove /index.php/ from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i can't remove the index.php on my codeigniter install...

my directorys looks like this:
root/.htaccess
root/index.php
root/applications
root/system

my .htaccess:

```
AcceptPathInfo On

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

any solution to fix that?

Comment: have you removed it from application/config.php, $config['index_page'] ?

Comment: i have $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: Mine is
`        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: i use puphet Debian Wheezy with Mod Rewrite enabled as apache2 modul.. any solution to fix it?

Comment: on xampp on windows it works like a charm but on my debian developement server not :/